# Is there a reason this array is padded out to 16 bytes?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

I have a storage buffer in GLSL in a shader:

```
struct DeviceSideTerrainPatchInfo
{
    ivec3 terrain_patch_pos_int;
    uint buffer_idx;
    vec3 terrain_patch_pos_frac;
    uint buffer_offset;
};


layout (std430, set = 2, binding = 2) readonly buffer TerrainInfoArray
{
    DeviceSideTerrainPatchInfo terrain_info_array[];
};
```

This is fine, each element is 32 bytes big and it indexes fine. However I add an extra member to the struct:

```
struct DeviceSideTerrainPatchInfo
{
    ivec3 terrain_patch_pos_int;
    uint buffer_idx;
    vec3 terrain_patch_pos_frac;
    uint buffer_offset;
    uint extra_member;
};


layout (std430, set = 2, binding = 2) readonly buffer TerrainInfoArray
{
    DeviceSideTerrainPatchInfo terrain_info_array[];
};
```

Now, I understand that under std140 rules that would be padded out to a size a multiple of 16, which would be 48. However under std430 rules there isn't that strict requirement and I was pretty sure each element of the array would be aligned to a multiple of 36. It turns out I need to add another 3 4-byte members on my host-side code to have it align properly, meaning with std430 it's aligned to 48.

Answer (score 1):

> However under std430 rules there isn't that strict requirement

I'm not sure why you would think that.  [The rules](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/opengl-programming-guide/9780132748445/app09lev1sec3.html) clearly state that vec3 will be aligned to 4 times the aligment of the element type -- so you get 16 byte alignment in this case.

Comment: I've added an extra uint member. The original is 32 bytes, and 32-byte aligned. I add a uint member. There is no vec3 to align to 16-byte boundary, the entire struct grew from 32 byte size to 36-byte size, how is it aligning a vec3?

Comment: The structure contains two vec3 components, so it gets aligned/padded to 16 bytes.  Structures are always aligned based on the worst-case (largest) alignment of any element -- adding elements with less alignment doesn't change anything.

Comment: What happens if I dont specify a layout when declaring a binding? Does it default to something?

Comment: It defaults to something driver-specific.  That may be the same as one of the std layouts or may be something else -- need to look at your GL driver's documentation to find out.

Comment: In particular, it might b the same as `packed`, which allows the compiler and driver to reorder the fields in the buffer to fit better.